# Problems with react router using regexp as a path

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, react-router

I need to let user type in a date in this form: 15-03-2018 in an adress bar. So naturally I thought to go with regexp since I read in React Router docs that this is supported. I tried adding a long date regexp and couldn't make it work. So i thought ill try with a simple regex like (abc*), and that works, but this doesn't:

```
    <Route path="/(^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\-)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\-)\d{4}$)" component={Dashboard} />
```

I tried excluding ^ and $ from the regex since that is only needed in a multiline input, that i don't need at the moment.
Couldn't find any resource to solve this, i'll be grateful if anyone can help me with this, thanks in advance!

p.s. This is my first question on stack overflow so if I made any formating errors, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Seem that the parser of the React Router works like this:
-Regex should be in placed in braces like this(), but any more complex regex that contains more braces in it self should be typed in separate braces like this:
example: (abc*)(abc*),
and not like this ((abc*)(abc*))

Lost my nerves with this, finnaly got it right, maybe it will help someone.